# MongoDB pipe (Golang) returning only one field of four inside the document

Tags: mongodb, api, go

I was trying to dump data received from a lookup using mgo/pkg package but when I receive data, dump it and return, I get this output:

```js
 [
  {
    "_id": "",
    "timerId": "",
    "content": "task1",
    "creationDate": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "",
    "timerId": "",
    "content": "task2",
    "creationDate": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "",
    "timerId": "",
    "content": "task3",
    "creationDate": 0
  }
]
```

Printing with fmt:

```
[{ObjectIdHex("") ObjectIdHex("") task1 0} {ObjectIdHex("") ObjectIdHex("") task2 0} {ObjectIdHex("") ObjectIdHex("") task3 0}]
```

Code that is performing this action:

```js
func (m *MongoDbRepository) GetTasksOnTheSameDateAsUserTimers(userId string)([]model.Task, error) {

 var tasks []model.Task
 // m.Db.Session.DB("project").C("tasks")
 pipe := m.Db.C("tasks").Pipe([]bson.M{
  // bson.M{
  //  "$lookup": bson.M{
  //   "from":   "times",
  //   "localField":  "timerId",
  //   "foreignField": "_id",
  //   "as":   "timers",
  //  },
  // },
  // bson.M{
  //  "$lookup": bson.M{
  //   "from":   "users",
  //   "localField":  "timers.userId",
  //   "foreignField": "_id",
  //   "as":   "userTasks",
  //  },
  // },
  // bson.M{
  //  "$project": bson.M{
  //   "timers": 0,
  //  },
  // },
  // bson.M{
  //  "$match": bson.M{ 
  //   "_id":bson.ObjectIdHex("5cb58c5c4d11610c20b52f1a"),
  //  },
  // },
 })

 err := pipe.All(&tasks)
 fmt.Println(tasks)
 return tasks, err
}
```

I have commented all inside pipe because I can't perform the lookup because of I can't get the result of the piping correctly. I know that is a dumping data error because if I change ending lines like this:

```js
var tasksDump []interface{}
err := pipe.All(&tasksDump)
fmt.Println(tasksDump)
```

Then this is the output:

```js
[map[_id:ObjectIdHex("5cb58c5c4d11610c20b52f1a") content:task1 creationDate:1555400713 timerId:ObjectIdHex("5cb5880891b3fb1e2830b743")] map[_id:ObjectIdHex("5cb58ccd4d11610c20b52f1b") content:task2 creationDate:1555400714 timerId:ObjectIdHex("5cb5880891b3fb1e2830b743")] map[_id:ObjectIdHex("5cb58d074d11610c20b52f1c") content:task3 creationDate:1555400700 timerId:ObjectIdHex("5cb5880891b3fb1e2830b743")]]
```

So data is arriving but when parse I have the issue. Why only content field is being parsed correctly?

Code of the struct where I am dumping data from lookup:

```js
type Task struct {
 Id   bson.ObjectId  `json:"_id"    bson:"_id"`
 TimerId   bson.ObjectId  `json:"timerId"   bson:"timerId"`
 Content   string   `json:"content"   bson:"content"`
 CreationDate         int64   `json:"creationDate"  bson:"creationDate"`
}
```

MongoDB collection from where I'm receiving data:

[image]

Comment: The field tags in `Task` are not compatible with [reflect.StructTag.Get](https://godoc.org/reflect#StructTag.Get).  Separate the pairs with spaces, not tabs.  The `go vet` command reports this error.

Comment: Yes, I realized 3 hours after '-_-. Thank you for your answer!